# What is the difference of Dreamcode and Unhosted Web Apps

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, dreamcode, unhosted

From [unhosted](https://unhosted.org/):

> By “unhosted web apps” we mean browser-based apps with no server-side
>   backend. Unlike server-side or client-server apps, unhosted web apps
>   leave users in control of their valuable user data and privacy, by
>   default.

From [noBackend](http://nobackend.org/) (dreamcode):

> noBackend is an approach to decouple apps from backends, by
>   abstracting backend tasks with frontend code (Dreamcode). This allows
>   frontend developers to focus on user experience and gives backend
>   developers more flexibility on the implementation side.

Are these two movements completely separate to each other unhosted is just the same as dreamcode?

- Is the Unhosted idea just suitable for apps that used to be desktop before, like note taking apps? Evernote for example. A unhosted kind of evernote would have the same functionality of a Evernote but data is not hosted in the application server?
- For the Dreamcode, is it more suitable for web applications that needs data or documents to be shared across different users of the app. Like a blogging site, a document hosting site or a social network site?

Comment: I noticed that the "dreamcode" and "unhosted" tags have no descriptions per the wiki (mouse over them). Could you add them?